# Python OS For Loop - TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, for-loop, pdf, module

I have the following code to iterate over each file in a folder and run the `pdfplumber` module on it:

```
#Import required packages:
import os
import pdfplumber

#Iterate over pdf's 
os.chdir(r'C:\MyDocuments\PDF')
directory = r'C:\MyDocuments\PDF'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):                              #iterate over each file in directory
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):                                   #if the file is a pdf (we will be creating .txt files - do not want to include these)
        pdf = pdfplumber(filename)                                  #pdfplumber extracts the pdf file first
    else:
        continue
```

There is more going on once the PDF is imported with `pdfplumber`, but this `for` loop gives the gist of the issue. When I run this, I get the error message

> `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

It seems that there should be a solution in something like: `from os import ...` where ... should be whatever function is needed (I think). If this is a solution though, I don't know which specific function I would need to import from os. If someone would have a suggestion on how to make this work, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

`pdfplumber` is itself the class name. You need to use `.open()` for this:

```
import os
import pdfplumber

#Iterate over pdf's 
os.chdir(r'C:\MyDocuments\PDF')
directory = r'C:\MyDocuments\PDF'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):                              #iterate over each file in directory
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):                                   #if the file is a pdf (we will be creating .txt files - do not want to include these)
        pdf = pdfplumber.open(filename)                                  #pdfplumber extracts the pdf file first
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice this. Thanks so much!